# Transpose a part of a table saving column names as a new column value [PostgreSQL]

Tags: postgresql, pivot, transpose

how can I transpose a part of a table saving column names as a new column value and merge these columns values into one?

Are there any ways to do this without hardcoding?

For example, I have table with such structure:

I've tried to use crosstab but didn't get how to extract column names. Also have tried to iterate over columns names generating a set of records but main problem is that source table is enormous.

| StoreHouse | Product | HasDiscount | IsOutOfStock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JohnStore | chair | False | True |
| SomeStore | table | True | False |

As a result I need output of such structure:

| StoreHouse | Product | Parameter | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JohnStore | chair | HasDiscount | False |
| JohnStore | chair | IsOutOfStock | True |
| SomeStore | table | HasDiscount | True |
| SomeStore | table | IsOutOfStock | False |

Comment: The appropriate solution would be to normalize your data. The result essentially would be defining and storing your data as your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Barring dynamic SQL, you need to know the column names and "hardcode" them in your table. Apart from that, you just need a union:

```
SELECT
  "StoreHouse",
  "Product",
  'HasDiscount' AS "Parameter",
  "HasDiscount" AS "Status"
FROM example
UNION ALL
SELECT
  "StoreHouse",
  "Product",
  'IsOutOfStock' AS "Parameter",
  "IsOutOfStock" AS "Status"
FROM example
```

Optionally order by `StoreHouse` and `Product`.